# How can I find the Cultists

Tags: terraria-console

I have defeated Skeletron Prime, The Twins, Destroyer, Plantera, and Golem, but still cannot find the cultists at the dungeon. I even made a new world and did the same thing but still no cultists.

Comment: even if im on xbox360, would that work for the pc version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

See the [Wiki page](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cultist).  At the very top:

> Desktop-Only Content: This information (or parts of it) applies only to the desktop version of Terraria.

Comment: Beat me there by 5 seconds Timmy :P

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to find the cultists in your game, the cultists are exclusive content to the PC version of Terraria so you will not be able to find them.

Source: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cultist

Comment: Well if you heard rumors of an update coming soon, which doesn't mean it exists right now, then there really isn't a point to your question - you answered it yourself.